# userContentController didReceiveScriptMessage method is not being called in iOS 8.1

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, ios8, wkwebview

I'm implementing **iOS 8.1** mobile application using webkit framework, I followed few steps, **to call the Javascript function in Objective-C**

**steps:**

- In viewDidLoad i have loaded html page from bundle.

`[contentWebVew loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlPath]]];`

```
    _webConfig = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc]init];
    WKUserContentController* userController = [[WKUserContentController alloc]init];
   [userController addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"loadingLessonsData"];
    _webConfig.userContentController = userController;
```

- Calling Javascript function using Objective C
- `NSString *exec_template = @"setLessonData(\"received: '%@'\");";
   NSString *exec = [NSString stringWithFormat:exec_template,@"tintintin"]; 
  [_contentWebVw evaluateJavaScript:exec completionHandler:nil];`

  Here, the issue is: I'm not able to execute any statements in "setLessonData" function.

-**This method is not calling**

```
- (void)userContentController:(WKUserContentController *)userContentController didReceiveScriptMessage:(WKScriptMessage *)message
```

The method executes only once, when i have run in multiple times.

Please let us know how to call the **didReceiveScriptMessage** method and how to pass a variable from JavaScript to objective C using iOS 8?

// Javascript Code

```
function setLessonData(_iOSBundlePath, _rootPath, _activities) {
alert("activity");
activities  = _activities;
rootPath    = _rootPath;
bundlePath  = _iOSBundlePath;
jsonEle     = JSON.parse(activities);
lessonData  = jsonEle.lesson;
showActivity();
}

function showActivity(){
stopAllSounds();
length = lessonData.activity.length;
validateButtons();
var temp = lessonData.activity[wrapper_counter].link;
path = bundlePath + '/' + temp + '/';
var activity_path = path + 'index.html';
alert("activity path:...."+activity_path);

$(".content").empty();
$(".content").load(activity_path,function(data){
    var s;
    alert("b4 trim content"+$(this).html());
    $(".content").each(function () {
        s = $.trim($(this).html()).replace(/assets/g, path+'assets');
    });
    alert("html content"+s);
    $(".content").empty();
    $(".content").append(s);
});
}
```

Comment: Any one have an idea about wkwebview?

Comment: Can you show the JavaScript part?